# serialize list of huge composite graphs using protobuf-net causing out-of-memory-exception

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net, large-data-volumes

I am trying to serialize an object containing a list of very large composite object graphs (~200000 nodes or more) using Protobuf-net. Basically what I want to achieve is to save the complete object into a single file as fast and as compact as possible.

My problem is that I get an out-of-memory-exception while trying to serialize the object. On my machine the exception is thrown when the file size is around 1.5GB. I am running a 64 bit process and using a StreamWriter as input to protobuf-net. Since I am writing directly to a file I suspect that some kind of buffering is taking place within protobuf-net causing the exception. I have tried to use the DataFormat = DataFormat.Group attribute but with no luck so far.

I can avoid the exception by serializing each composite in the list to a separate file but I would prefer to have it all done in one go if possible.

Am I doing something wrong or is it simply not possible to achieve what i want?

Code to illustrate the problem:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int numberOfTrees = 250;
        int nodesPrTree = 200000;

        var trees = CreateTrees(numberOfTrees, nodesPrTree);
        var forest = new Forest(trees);

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter("model.bin"))
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(writer.BaseStream, forest);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static Tree[] CreateTrees(int numberOfTrees, int nodesPrTree)
    {
        var trees = new Tree[numberOfTrees];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTrees; i++)
        {
            var root = new Node();
            CreateTree(root, nodesPrTree, 0);
            var binTree = new Tree(root);
            trees[i] = binTree;
        }
        return trees;
    }

    private static void CreateTree(INode tree, int nodesPrTree, int currentNumberOfNodes)
    {
        Queue<INode> q = new Queue<INode>();
        q.Enqueue(tree);
        while (q.Count > 0 && currentNumberOfNodes < nodesPrTree)
        {
            var n = q.Dequeue();
            n.Left = new Node();
            q.Enqueue(n.Left);
            currentNumberOfNodes++;

            n.Right = new Node();
            q.Enqueue(n.Right);
            currentNumberOfNodes++;
        }
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Node), DataFormat = DataFormat.Group)]
public interface INode
{
    [ProtoMember(2, DataFormat = DataFormat.Group, AsReference = true)]
    INode Parent { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3, DataFormat = DataFormat.Group, AsReference = true)]
    INode Left { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(4, DataFormat = DataFormat.Group, AsReference = true)]        
    INode Right { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Node : INode
{
    INode m_parent;
    INode m_left;
    INode m_right;

    public INode Left
    {
        get
        {
            return m_left;
        }
        set
        {
            m_left = value;
            m_left.Parent = null;
            m_left.Parent = this;
        }
    }

    public INode Right
    {
        get
        {
            return m_right;
        }
        set
        {
            m_right = value;
            m_right.Parent = null;
            m_right.Parent = this;
        }
    }

    public INode Parent
    {
        get
        {
            return m_parent;
        }
        set
        {
            m_parent = value;
        }
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Tree
{
    [ProtoMember(1, DataFormat = DataFormat.Group)]
    public readonly INode Root;

    public Tree(INode root)
    {
        Root = root;
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Forest
{
    [ProtoMember(1, DataFormat = DataFormat.Group)]
    public readonly Tree[] Trees;

    public Forest(Tree[] trees)
    {
        Trees = trees;
    }
}
```

Stack-trace when the exception is thrown:

```
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Resize(Int32 newSize, Boolean forceNewHashCodes)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
at ProtoBuf.NetObjectCache.AddObjectKey(Object value, Boolean& existing) in NetObjectCache.cs:line 154
at ProtoBuf.BclHelpers.WriteNetObject(Object value, ProtoWriter dest, Int32 key, NetObjectOptions options) BclHelpers.cs:line 500
at proto_5(Object , ProtoWriter )
```

I am trying to do a workaround where I serialize the array of trees one at a time to a single file using the SerializeWithLengthPrefix method. Serialization seems work - I can see the filesize is increased after each tree in the list is added to the file. However, when I try to Deserialize the trees I get the Invalid wire-type exception. I am creating a new file when I serialize the trees so the file should be garbage free - unless I am writing garbage of cause ;-). My serialize and deserialization methods are listed below:

```
using (var writer = new FileStream("model.bin", FileMode.Create))
{
    foreach (var tree in trees)
    {
        Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(writer, tree, PrefixStyle.Base128);
    }
}

using (var reader = new FileStream("model.bin", FileMode.Open))
{
    var trees = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<Tree[]>>(reader, PrefixStyle.Base128);
}
```

Am I using the method in a incorrect way?

Comment: On mobile at the moment - will run it through a debugger later

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks! looking forward to your findings

Comment: side note; it *looks* like you're actually double-serializing at the moment, because your `Parent` / `Left` / `Right` are serialized **both** on the interface **and** the public `Node` API. I've removed the attributes from `Node` in my local - it'll still hit the dictionary limit, but it will probably use half the disk space when dictionary dies :) edit: yup - 840MB when dying now.

Comment: slightly content that `BinaryFormatter` *also* dies in this particular scenario :p But: if you can confirm for me the stack-trace is the `Dictionary`2.Resize` issue, then it is *probably solvable* without too much pain... what's a little sharding between friends, eh?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the double serialization. It also dies at 840MB on my machine with this correction. I'm still very new to protobuf-net so if you see anything else that looks strange please point it out :-). I'll update with a stacktrace shortly.

Comment: I have added the stack-trace and it shows - as you suspected - that it is the Dictionary'2.Resize issue. Is it solvable?

Comment: @mda I honestly don't know. I did some work last night to try implementing sharding - but I think I have some kinks  to figure out

Comment: @MarcGravell Sounds grim. Please let me know if there is anything I can do to help the process. I can get by using the serialize each composite to a seperate file, but it would of cause be preferable to have support for this scenario. At least if it is beneficial to other projects than this one.

Comment: @MarcGravell As a side question. Is there a way to serialize the composite graphs separately but to a single file using protobuf-net?

Comment: @mda if you have a sequence of separate pieces, then `SerializeWithLengthPrefix` (and the similar to deserialize) should allow for that.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks, I will give SerializeWithLengthPrefix a try later today. And a big thanks for taking the time to look into this.

Comment: @MarkGravel, did either of you solve this out-of-memory-exception while serializing larger object structures?

Comment: @oakman, I ended up modifying my structure to make it more compact and efficient. So sadly, I never found a solution for the out-of-memory-exception.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't *helping* that the `AsReference` code was only respecting default data-format, which means it was trying to hold data in memory so that it can write the object-length prefix back into the data-stream, which is exactly what we **don't** want here (hence your quite correct use of `DataFormat.Group`). That will account for buffering for an individual branch of the tree. I've tweaked it locally, and I can definitely confirm that it is now writing forwards-only (the debug build has a convenient `ForwardsOnly` flag that I can enable which detects this and shouts).

With that tweak, I have had it work for 250 x 20,000, but I'm getting secondary problems with the dictionary resizing (even in x64) when working on the 250 x 200,000 - like you say, at around the 1.5GB level. It occurs to me, however, that I might be able to discard one of these (forwards or reverse) respectively when doing each of serialization / deserialization. I would be interested in the stack-trace when it breaks for you - if it is ultimately the dictionary resize, I may need to think about moving to a *group* of dictionaries...